# Android rtl stopped working

Tags: android

My app does specify supportRtl = true in the manifest

But all of a sudden, I don't know what caused this, but my app layout in Hebrew in still ltr.

I can't explain this, has anyone have experienced that before?

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion ?

Comment: @idaNakav 14, but it was like also before, so I don't think it is related

Comment: sry meant to ask about targetSdkVersion, make sure it's 17+, otherwise this attribute will be ignored

Comment: It is, please note that it used to work before, I suspect it has to do with updated build tools, play services library or something like this, I wanted to know if others has experienced that too